# Find component using CSS selector in TestUtils

Tags: jasmine, reactjs, reactjs-testutils

I'm writing some simple tests for my React components using **TestUtils** and I'm finding that both the `TestUtils.FindRenderedDOMComponentWithClass` and `TestUtils.FindRenderedDOMComponentWithTag` methods are pretty **limiting**. I'd like to find a component using the typical CSS selector (i.e. `tag.class [attr]`) but it doesn't seem like this is an option.

Is there a simple way to find an element with a specific attribute? If not are there any useful tools for finding components apart from `TestUtils`?

Comment: I know that jQuery added support for Node.js on 2.1.x. Did anybody tested it being used together with React Test Utils? I think jQuery isn't the best option on the client anymore. But it would be a hell of a testing tool for Angular and React on the server

Comment: It 's unreal http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/11/reacttestutils-find-element-by.html#.Wfh8EhO0Oi4

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful to simply use the browser's [`Element.querySelector()/querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) method on DOM elements.

You can just call for example like this:

```
var domElement = FindRenderedDOMComponentWithClass('myClass');
var firstTextInput = domElement.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

`React.TestUtils` does **not** offer component searches with CSS selectors so I went with a lightweight extension of the base `TestUtils` class called  [react-testutils-addition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-testutils-additions). It offeres a `find()` method which parses the CSS selector style input and uses `TestUtils.findAllInRenderedTree` to find the component.